# is it possible to publish html report with relative path in azure devops pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have html reports with reference relative paths and I am trying to publish the index.html which has relative paths to 2 more html reports.
like index.html has ref to content.html and ../../result.txt.

When I publish index.html using publishhtmlreport@1 task in azure pipeline, it says blob not found error.
*BlobNotFoundThe specified blob does not exist.*
if I publish content.html, it shows the content of content.html, but the links inside this are not working.

is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to publish HTML reports with relative paths in Azure DevOps pipeline. The issue you're facing might be due to the way the publishhtmlreport@1 task handles relative paths.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/path_to_your_reports_directory'
    artifactName: 'Reports'
```

Instead of directly publishing the HTML report, consider publishing the entire directory as an artifact using the PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task. This will ensure all the related files are available. I hope this helps! Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: What does `PublishBuildArtifacts@1` have to do with `PublishHtmlReport`? They are different. Also, you should prefer using `PublishPipelineArtifacts` over `PublishBuildArtifacts` as it is designed to be much faster and serves as a replacement for `PublishBuildArtifacts`.

Comment: Can't agree more. Issue is with publishing html report.